# Accessing default MS SQL Server database over tcp\ip

Tags: c#, sql-server

I use following c# code to connect to a MS SQL 2014 express database:

```
public static string sqlhost = Properties.Settings.Default.Opt_SQLServer;

public static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + sqlhost +"; Initial Catalog=virtualNetwork1;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

I also replaced the "sqlhost" with IP-adress for testing.
"Shared Memory", "Named Pipes" and " TCP/IP" configuration on sql server is activated, but I can`t run my software on a remote pc. Firewall is also deactivated.

Do you know which connection method this c# string is using and why I can`t connect from a remote pc ?

Comment: service 1433 is listening only on ip address 0.0.0.0 (??)

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the value ov `sqlhost` ? Is it a valid server name? The type of protocol actually depends on the server addres you pass - `(local)` will look for Shared Memory first, while an IP address,  `localhost` or an FQDN will be strictly TCP/IP

Comment: Error Message: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

Comment: sqlhost is the hostname of my computer (no FQDN)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165647(v=sql.90).aspx), network access is disabled by default on SQL Server express. Good thing, the document also describes how to enable it for you :)